# Necesito actualizar la versión php de mi sitio web con wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Veran, estoy haciendo un sitio web (mi primero de hecho) es una tienda online para hacer dropshiping, y cuando instalo un plugin de dropshiping me dice que solo es compatible con versiones php de 7.1 en adelante, entonces al intentar actualizar mi sitio desde el cpannel, y establezco la version php como 7.2 no sucede nada, el plugin de display php version me sigue marcando que la versión que esta ejecutandose es la 5.6. Ya he intentado desde el cpannel varias veces y nada, necesito ayuda con esto por favor.

Comment: ¿Ya reiniciaste el apache?

Comment: Es muy raro que hayas cambiado la versión de PHP en el servidor y que WP te siga tomando la versión antigua. Revisa si en el `.htaccess` del directorio `public_html` no hay una línea como esta o parecida: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php` Si no está, prueba a limpiar la caché del navegador o, si es posible, desde otro dispositivo.

Comment: Ya revise el .htaccess y la linea que estaba la cambie AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php y tampoco sucedio nada, no afecto en lo mas minimo.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la configuración del servidor, el sistema operativo debe contar con los sources necesarios para instalar nuevas versiones de PHP ( Lo cual no puedes cambiar ).

El proceso si php 7.x es soportado seria el siguiente.

Click en PHP Configuration

[image: php configuration]

Seleccionar la version de PHP

[image: select]

Y guardar

> Esto puede ser distinto según el servidor y la version de CPanel, pero
>   no hay alguna razón adicional para que el proceso no funcione,
>   simplemente el servidor no soporta otra version de PHP.

Comment: Puede que sea eso. que el servidor no soporta la otra version de php? en dado caso que deberia hacer, cambiar de proveedor hosting?

Comment: Exactamente, eso mismo